# Does anyone know how to solve this proof in TFL ¬¬¬A → A ⊢ ¬A → ⊥?

Tags: logic

I have been struggling for the past couple of hours and if anyone has any tips, please let me know. I am very lost in subproofs in general and would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how are you trapped in this really easy problem, and why this is no in Mathematics SE, but here is the solution.

```
| 1. ¬¬¬A → A                       Premise
| | 2. ¬A                           Assumption
| | 3. ¬¬¬A                         Introduction Double negation from 2
| | 4. A                            Implication elimination of 1 with 3
| | 5. ⊥                            Negation Elimination of 4 with 2
| 6. ¬A → ⊥                         Implication introduction from 2 to 5
```

And the conclusion is obvious

Comment: I don't know why you solve other people's homework.

Comment: How do we do what you did? I can't seem to use LaTex commands in Philosophy SE

Comment: @Mr.White, the questioner **Alina Smirnova** was quite clear. She wanted "some **tips**", not the solution. Stupid me!

Answer (score 1):

```
1. ~~~A imples A [premise]
2. ~A [assume for conditional proof]
3. ~~~A [2 double negation]
4. A [1, 3 modus ponens]
5. ~A & A [2, 3 conjuntion]
6. A & ~A [5 communtation]
7. ~A implies (A & ~A) [2 - 6 conditional proof]

QED
```